# Bitcoin Explorer - Truth or did i just got my wallet stolen?

Tags: wallet

So there is this webpage being advertised: http://allseeingbiteye.tk/

And the way it is advertised is: You can be tracked! Be careful of what you pay for. Bitcoin is as insecure and non-anonymous as a public toilet.

Obviously i got interested in it and ran the application, without administrative rights ofcourse.

With my security options, applications sometimes simply does not start until they are given administrative privileges...as soon as i ran that exe i realised that this could very well be sopfisticated scam to steal my wallet.

So anyone have any information about that site?

Comment: Can't speak from experience, but that site is blocked by websense at my workplace as "Phishing or other fraud" - I'd be careful.

Comment: If you haven't already you should move your coins to new addresses, just incase.

Comment: Website looks like something that would be aimed at getting your wallet.dat. Tried scanning it with some antivirus software?

Comment: Move your Bitcoin to a new address that is generated on a fresh, secure computer, that only has Bitcoin installed and nothing else. Preferably running linux.

Comment: Never heard of this website, but based on what you said alone I'm about 99% sure this is a scam. You should learn what signs to look for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to [a post by grue](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?topic=61491.msg718150#msg718150), the program from the website adds another executable to system startup, so it certainly behaves like a virus. You should get your computer checked.

Advise for the future - don't trust any .exe file unless you know the source or the owner. If you're not sure whether to trust someone or some website, ask either here, or on the forum. The community is quite sensitive about security and you can be pretty sure to get some good feedback if you ask.

Comment: Do not trust *any* .exe file unless you have reason to believe it's not harmful.

Comment: Windows security policy: trust it with your life and love or don't even touch it.

Comment: Thanks, obviously i was stupid by launching this application.