# How can I identify the coin type from its address?

Tags: alternatives, address

I know Bitcoin addresses start with `1`, and it seems that testnet addresses start with `m` or `n`, and Namecoin addresses start with `N`, but is there a more complete list that would allow me to identify the coin type from an address?  I hope this isn't offtopic, asking about other block chains.

I specifically want to know what these addresses are for (they're embedded in the executable linked to in [this question](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/q/2778/659)):

```
3Q9yidc7Sqwj4fkFmomzC4fqyFzNGTA21x
3Nw1sp46VjHyVDDAaQhDHZSX4xvoqNzrBs
3NjPgjfMAAbamPE5PcgvXHSkCzq4kqijpH
```

but a complete list associating address prefixes with coin types would be more useful.

Comment: According to the last paragraph in https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/BIP_0013#Rationale it looks like these are Bitcoin addresses, valid under BIP 13.  Is it possible this in-the-wild malware is ready for P2SH before the official client is?

Comment: Alternative blockchain-based currencies are on-topic, see http://meta.bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/15/are-questions-about-other-crypto-currencies-on-topic .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a list [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Base58Check_encoding#Version_bytes), and a more detailed one [here](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes). 3 is indeed for a Bitcoin script hash.

Comment: I looked at http://blockexplorer.com/testnet/block/00000000f2094d5227b836ef4c7ea23f9a3f248e7eb6ac487a49c54ced55e531 to see some example testnet addresses.  They start with 'm' and 'n' there...  I'm guessing the wiki page is wrong.

Comment: I was hoping for a more complete list - there are all kinds of altchains (solidcoin, litecoin, tenebrix, ixcoin, geistgeld (?), etc.), none of which I care about, but it would be useful to have a definitive list that would let me know what kind of an address I was looking at.

Comment: The wiki page was changed in this revision: https://en.bitcoin.it/w/index.php?title=Base58Check_encoding&diff=20952&oldid=20486 - the same change which makes the page say things like "Bitcoin addresses always start with the digit '3'".

Comment: Sounds like the kind of edit Luke would make. I created a more complete list at https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/List_of_address_prefixes , but it still requires some work.

Comment: Thanks Meni.  I worked on your page a bit, filling in all the missing values.  There are probably more altchains that need adding though.

Comment: @ChrisMoore Great work.